# Merge changes from branch into different branch without merging the branch

Tags: xcode, git, merge

I had a process in place where I would work on separate 'development' branches then merge them into the 'stable' master branch when finished. I would then create a new branch for the next development branch created from master. This ensured each development branch would always contain the most recent stable changes. But I made a mistake. I forgot to merge a development branch into master, but then I created a new branch from master and worked on it a lot. So this new branch that has a lot of changes is not up to date with the latest stable changes.

I went ahead and merged the previous development branch into master - the one I forgot to merge. Now I need to merge the changes from master into my newest development branch. But I don't actually want to merge the master branch into the dev branch, bringing along all of its history. I want these branches to remain separate, I just want to compare the differences between the two branches and merge the appropriate code from master into the dev branch as a single new commit. I know there will be conflicts. How can that be accomplished?

If possible, I would prefer to do this visually with Xcode's Source Control to compare and select the changes, but if not using Terminal is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario:

- You created a feature branch off of master.
- You merged new work into master ("new" is being used here as work that differs from when you created the feature branch).
- You now want to ensure that your feature branch is up to date with what's currently on master, but don't want to actually merge master in.

What you can do in this scenario is [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) your branch against master.

```
# When on your feature branch:
git rebase master
```

This will ensure that the work you have done beforehand appears after any new work that exists on master.  It also rewrites history, so if you've pushed that feature branch at any point, you'll have to force-push it to ensure that the correct history is maintained.

To clarify my last point:  when you rebase, you [overwrite the history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) of your commits by creating a commit that's similar to another one, but isn't the same as it (different ancestor).

The main guiding principle here is that history has changed, and if that history has been published, you will want to ensure that the history with the rebased changes are published *instead* so that history appears as it should with respect to the rebase operation.

Comment: This appears to be my scenario. I would note that the new dev branch contains a lot of changes, including pushes to it, that master does not have. I know there are going to be merge conflicts. I wouldn't want the dev branch's history to be erased, nor the history of master of course. If you could expand upon your last paragraph I would appreciate it. Specifically, I'm not sure what you mean by force-pushing to preserve history.

Comment: You don't lose the history, you merely change it.  That is to say, Git identifies it as a new thing that has happened, but it's a very specific commit that was replayed to appear in a certain ancestral order.

Comment: I went ahead with the rebase. I resolved the conflicts, ran `git rebase --continue`, it applied my commits I made to the dev branch, then it logged `Revert "Merge branch 'master' into dev-branch"`. All looked well on the Terminal, but looking at the code it has not made any difference - the changes from master are not merged into dev-branch. There's no uncommitted changes.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about a revert.  If you haven't pushed the rebase yet, perform a `git reset --hard origin/dev-branch`, then revert the revert:  `git revert <SHA>`.

Comment: How do I get the SHA for the revert, it's no longer shown in `git log` after performing the reset

Comment: I decided to manually add the changes from the master branch to the latest dev branch using `git diff`. Was a lot quicker than dealing with rebase, resolve merge conflicts, reset, revert, etc - will be careful not to make that mistake again

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the --squah modifier when merging. This will merge the code but will not create a commit merging the histories of the two branches.

See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge